# How to force vaadin AbstractJavaScriptComponent javascript to re-download when javascript file is changed

Tags: vaadin

In my Vaadin project, I have a component which extends `AbstractJavaScriptComponent`. I have added the javascript of the component using `@JavaScript` annotation.

```
@JavaScript({"app://./VAADIN/js/my-comp-connector.js"})
public class MyComp extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {
}
```

Whenever I do a change to `my-comp-connector.js`, I need to clean browser cache so that browser re-downloads the changed javascript.

How can I force re-download of the javascript when I do a change to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by adding a query parameter to javascript path specified in `@JavaScript` annotation.

```
@JavaScript({"app://./VAADIN/js/my-comp-connector.js?v=2"})
public class MyComp extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {
}
```